# SQL request syntax

Tags: php, sql, request

I have a query like that :

```
$modifiedDate1 = date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO file (filename, modifiedDate1) VALUES ".implode(',', $filenames)."".$modifiedDate1."";
```

I have an error in my SQL syntax for my second values, why ?

error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'January 01 1970 01:00:00.' at line 1
```

if it helps the entire code is :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=check', 'root', 'root');

if ($handle = opendir('check')) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..') {
            $filenames[] = "('".$file."')";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

$modifiedDate1 = date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));

/* insert new record into the table filenames with the filename */
$query = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO file (filename,modifiedDate1) VALUES ('".implode(',', $filenames)."".$modifiedDate1."')");

$stmt = $pdo->exec($query);   
    if (!$stmt) {
   echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
   print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}
    print "finished installing your files!";
```

This code is to compare if file's data already exist in the database.

Comment: please edit your question and explain more.

Comment: @NimaNr ok, Thats done

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) so you could safely escape your strings to avoid SQL injection.

Also it looks like your `$try` variable is qouted but I doubt this is the error, please vardump your `$try` or echo it and show your content so I can update my answer.

EDIT:

In your query as of now you haven't used single qoutes ' ' to qoute your variables.
this: `'".implode(',', $filenames)."".$modifiedDate1."'";` should work.

Comment: I updated my code to make it clear. A var_dump of my variable show a date, thats what I want

Comment: your edit doesn't work. Actually when i keep the first syntax, and I put nothing in my variable, I have no error. When I put string, or date in it, the error is here. Why the variable content makes the error ?

Comment: @maevy is the column you insert into perhaps a datetime column? because those don't handle the use of January 01 1970 01:00:00 but instead only Ie 2014-11-04 16:45:35

Comment: my column is a text one

Comment: @maevy try this: `"INSERT IGNORE INTO file (filename, modifiedDate1) VALUES ('".implode(',', $filenames)."','".$modifiedDate1."')";`

Comment: no.. I think the error is from another thing. Maybe mysql connect? I updated my first post to add my entire code if it helps.

Comment: @maevy In your query try qouting it and use () `INSERT IGNORE INTO file (filename) VALUES ('".implode(',', $filenames)."".$modifiedDate1."')";` I've tried this and it works

Comment: I updated my code with pdo connection. I tried your last proposition, and I don't know why its not working with me.. Look at my updated code

Comment: @maevy what is your current error still incorrect sql query?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near... (filenames)

Comment: @maevy That shouldn't happen... uhmm.... all of your code is correct the table name is file right?

Comment: Yes they are, that is totally weird :(

Comment: I found another way to do what I wanted with another code... Thank you Stijn Bernards